# Unable to add EC2 instance to load balancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ec2

This seems like an easy step in the process, but I've been left scratching my head.

I am setting up an elastic load balancer on AWS, however when I get to the step to add EC2 instances, it does not list all of the instances I am running. I attempted to add the instance to the load balancer using the AWS command line, but received this message:

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Simply --instances instance-id 
Invalid endpoint: https://elasticloadbalancing.N. Virginia.amazonaws.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you in the right region?

Comment: The instance is in the N. Virginia region, which is where I've set up the load balancer

Comment: what is the command you used to try to add it?

Comment: aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Simply --instances instance-id (instance-id is the id of the instance)

Comment: you are sure the load balance name is Simply? I think it just doesn't like that name.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the name is Simply. It seems like the EC2 instance isn't available to add, because it also doesn't show it as an option in the aws management console.

Comment: what happens if you list instances in that elb?

Comment: In the aws management console -> "There are no instances registered to this load balancer"

Comment: Sorry, what command can I use for this?

Comment: `aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name LoadBalancerName`

Comment: I'm getting the same error as the original. "Invalid endpoint: https://elasticloadbalancing.N. Virginia.amazonaws.com"

Comment: then I would say you aren't using the right name

Comment: for the fun of it, add `--region=us-east-1`. and edit your question to show your aws-cli configuration.

Comment: I added the --region=us-east-1 and it says the instance is in VPC. I guess I will look into setting it up for an instance in VPC and comment back if I have any more questions. Thanks to you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrectly set the region to be `N. Virginia` in the CLI configuration.

It should be: `us-east-1`

For a list of region names see: [Regions and Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)